# what does "NameError: name 'symbols' is not defined" mean?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

This is my very first experience with sympy.  I am usingDEbian bullseye with pythong.  I installed git then "git clone [https://github.com/sympy/sympy.git"](https://github.com/sympy/sympy.git%22) Following that:

```
abraca@SS:~/SymPy$ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = symbols('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'symbols' is not defined
>>> quit()
```

What have I done wrong?

Here is what my tree looks like, starting from my root directory:

```
abraca@SS:~$ ls SymPy/sympy/sympy
abc.py         core         integrals         polys       tensor
algebras       crypto       interactive       printing    testing
assumptions    diffgeom     liealgebras       release.py  this.py
benchmarks     discrete     logic             sandbox     unify
calculus       external     matrices          series       utilities
categories     functions    multipledispatch  sets        vector
codegen        galgebra.py  ntheory           simplify
combinatorics  geometry     parsing           solvers
concrete       holonomic    physics           stats
conftest.py    __init__.py  plotting          strategies
```

Comment: `NameError` means that the variable has not been created or defined, as the error says.  But that `sympy` import should import a function with that name.  So that means there's something unexpected about the `sympy` module; it isn't what you (and we) expect it to be.

Comment: @Carcigenate.  There is a sympy but no sympy.py

Comment: @hpaulj  I have shown the directory tree in my edded original question.  I issued the git request from a new directory I called SymPy.  It seems git created a sympy directory that contains another synpy directory that contains commands.  Could you suggest where all this ought to reside to make sense?  Thanks much

Comment: @Carcigenicate.  Just as in my reply to hpaulj, Could you indicate where the sympy directory installed by git should reside so that Python will find it when I invoke the import command, while no getting confused because it is in the same place?  Also is there a better way to install sympy (e.g. sudo apt install sympy

Answer (score 1):

Installing sympy via git never worked. Here is what did work (note the all important 3, placed after `python`, not `pip`):

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install sympy
```

From then on it all works:

```
abraca@SS:~$ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x=symbols('x')
>>> limit(sin(x)/x,x,0)
1
>>> quit()
abraca@SS:~$
```